# Python, faster way to read fixed length fields from a file into dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, performance

I have a file of names and addresses as follows (example line)

```
OSCAR    ,CANNONS      ,8     ,STIEGLITZ CIRCUIT
```

And I want to read it into a dictionary of name and value.  Here self.field_list  is a list of the name, length and start point of the fixed fields in the file.  What ways are there to speed up this method?  (python 2.6)

```
def line_to_dictionary(self, file_line,rec_num):
  file_line = file_line.lower()  # Make it all lowercase

  return_rec = {}  # Return record as a dictionary

  for (field_start, field_length, field_name) in self.field_list:

    field_data = file_line[field_start:field_start+field_length]

    if self.strip_fields == True:  # Strip off white spaces first
      field_data = field_data.strip()

    if field_data != '':  # Only add non-empty fields to dictionary
      return_rec[field_name] = field_data

  # Set hidden fields
  #
  return_rec['_rec_num_'] = rec_num
  return_rec['_dataset_name_'] = self.name
  return return_rec
```

Comment: Cant you just handle it like a normal csv file? Maybe running strip() on the values. Does it matter that the values were fixed length at the time of writing?

Comment: I've read through the code I've been given to improve and it appears that the fixed length fields overlap, so for instance you have (name:start:length) fname:1:10 and fname_initial:1:1  I'm frustrated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get some speed up, you can also store `field_start+field_length` directly in self.field_list, instead of storing `field_length`.

Also, `if field_data != ''` can more simply be written as `if field_data` (if this gives any speed up, it is marginal, though).

I would say that your method is quite fast, compared to what standard Python can do (i.e., without using non-standard, dedicated modules).

Answer (score 2):

[`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) combined with `s` specifiers with lengths will tear the string apart faster than slicing.

Comment: Tried this out but not sure how to deal with overlapping fields

Comment: ... Overlapping fields? Who came up with that one?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Just saw your remark below about commas.  The approach below is fast when it comes to file reading, but it is delimiter-based, and would fail in your case.  It's useful in other cases, though.

If you want to read the file really fast, you can use a dedicated module, such as the almost standard [Numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html):

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('file_name.txt', dtype=('S10', 'S8'), delimiter=',')   # dtype must be adapted to your column sizes
```

`loadtxt()` also allows you to process fields on the fly (with the `converters` argument).  Numpy also allows you to give names to columns (see the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)), so that you can do:

```
data['name'][42]  # Name # 42
```

The structure obtained is like an Excel array; it is quite memory efficient, compared to a dictionary.

If you really need to use a dictionary, you can use a dedicated loop over the `data` array read quickly by Numpy, in a way similar to what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines include commas like the example, you can use line.split(',') instead of several slices. This may prove to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

It handle not only csv, but any csv-like format which yours seems to be.

Comment: Unfortunately "CSV-like" may not be enough. It may be possible for fields to contain embedded commas, at which point both `csv` and `line.split(',')` will fail horribly.